# How to locate a row with only one set of parentheses using perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have these lines of row in a file, for example:

```
row 1 (ddkdkdkdeieie) (ddkdkdkdeieie) (ddkdkdkdeieie)
row 2 (ddkdkdkdeieie)
row 3 (ddkdkdkdeieie) (ddkdkdkdeieie)
row 4 (ddkdkdkdeieie)
```

I'm trying to locate a pattern with rows of only one set of parentheses. In the example above, that would be row 2 and 4.

I tried this but not working using perl regex....

```
     /^\(.*\)$/
```

Comment: Why, o why you want to solve it with regex?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if !/(?:\).*\()/;
}

__DATA__
row 1 (ddkdkdkdeieie) (ddkdkdkdeieie) (ddkdkdkdeieie)
row 2 (ddkdkdkdeieie)
row 3 (ddkdkdkdeieie) (ddkdkdkdeieie)
row 4 (ddkdkdkdeieie)
```

Output:

```
row 2 (ddkdkdkdeieie)
row 4 (ddkdkdkdeieie)
```